# How to merge two SQL queries in VBA with one similar column?

Tags: mysql, vba

I have two SQL tables (table1 and table2), one of which contains dates for each day (column [dte_Date]) and the according level of an index (like the S&P 500) (column [flt_Close]), the other contains dates for each day (column [dte_ReportDate]) and the according prices for a product (column ([flt_Price]). I would like to make a VBA macro with two queries and then display in a Worksheet three columns :

```
DATE - LEVEL of the INDEX - Price of the PRODUCT
...  - ...                - ...
```

and so on. Unfortunately, the two tables don't always have the same dates so I can not write the first table and then fill the last column with the price of the product because the dates don't necessarily match.

So, how to make sure that I correctly fill the worksheet (if for one date there is only one value, then I want to display it and display "0" or "No value" for the other column) ?

Here is how the table look (table1) :

```
[dte_Date] ... [flt_Close]
2015-01-01 ...    2000
2015-01-02 ...    2010
2015-01-03 ...    2020
```

and (table2) :

```
[dte_ReportDate] ... [flt_Price]
2015-01-01       ...    10
2015-01-03       ...    11
```

and that would be the result I would like to have in my Excel worksheet:

```
DATE ... Close ... Price
01/01/15  2000       10
01/02/15  2010      No value (or 0)
01/03/15  2020       11
```

Comment: create an outerjoin sql query and move the result to excel

Comment: See Joins and Unions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: thanks to both of you, works perfectly !